# How to delay Facebook Messenger Bots with the dots like they are typing

Tags: facebook, bots, facebook-messenger

I don't see any setting on the Facebook configuration page that would give the ... while the bot is "typing" but I've heard it's configurable?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The three dots appear automatically after a message is sent, leaving you enough time to generate a response.

Edit: This was the case but the API changed. This question is a duplicate and the real answer can be found in the link to the original question.

Comment: so they're standard for a Messenger BOT?  In testing when I chat at my BOT I don't get the three dots prior to his responding?

Comment: I wonder how this is accepted since I don't think this really is the case...